# boostrap modal call functions on footer buttons click

Tags: jquery, function, button, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to build a configurable modal window on bootstrap. My intentions is to fill dynamically a modal by creation function arguments.

One parameter is the title of the header(`titolo`), the second(`messaggio`) is the text of the modal body that could be html or plain text, the third(`conferma`) is the function called if the confirm button(created if this function is present) is clicked and the forth(`callback`) is the callback function called if the modal window is closed.

Unfortunately I can't get it working, can you help me?

```
function apriModal(titolo,messaggio,conferma,callback){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var re=new RegExp("</?\w+\s+[^>]*>");
    $("#modalHeaderTitle").text(titolo);
    if(messaggio.match(re)){
        $("#modalBodyText").html(messaggio);
    }
    else{
        $("#modalBodyText").html("<p>"+messaggio+"</p>");
    }
    (typeof conferma == 'function') ? $("#modalConfirm").show() : $("#modalConfirm").hide();
    $("#finestraModal").modal('show');
    $("#modalConfirm").click(function(){
        if(conferma){
            $("#finestraModal").modal('hide');
            conferma.apply();
        }
    });
    $("#modalClose").click(function(){
        if(callback){
            callback.apply();
        }
        $("#finestraModal").modal('hide');
    });
}
```

and here's the basic html of the modal:

```
<div id="finestraModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 id="modalHeaderTitle"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modalBodyText">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" id="modalClose" class="btn">Chiudi</a>
        <a href="#" id="modalConfirm" class="btn btn-primary">Conferma</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3EnA/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `jQuery.noConflict()` but continue use `$` in the following script.

```
function apriModal(titolo,messaggio,conferma,callback){
    jQuery.noConflict();
```

should change to

```
function apriModal(titolo,messaggio,conferma,callback){
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); // or other variable name
```

If you want to use other library, you can assign `jQuery.noConflict()` to another variable as shown in my demo or use `jQuery` when you needed.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/X3EnA/1/

Comment: I didn't know that.. I've spent a couple of hours checking the code.. Thank you so much!!!! You saved me a lot of hours of desperation!   But i still have a problem. My code attaches a news event handler every time the modal is opened so if I open the modal 3 times i have the conferma and callback functions executed 3 times. How may I fix that?

Comment: You can use `.off()` before `.click()` to remove the event handler. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/X3EnA/2/